# Как узнать, кто нажал на кнопку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

```
def Admin_Text (message):
    try:
        text = message.text
        if text.lower() == "/start" or text.lower() == "start" or text.lower() == 'меню':
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Пожалуйста не используйте команду Start!")
        else:
            key = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            key1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Взял", callback_data="Vzal")
            key2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Отмена", callback_data="Otmena")
            key.add(key1, key2)
            bot.send_message(chat_id=, text="" + text + "\n\n" + "Логин отправителя: @" + str(message.from_user.username), reply_markup=key)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Сообщение было отправлено, ожидайте!")
            logging.info("инициатор запроса - ID " + str(message.from_user.id) + "; " + "L - " + str(message.from_user.username))
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error("Ошибка (Admin_Text): " + str(ex))
```

Это сообщение, которое отправляется в другой чат с кнопками, потом оно обрабатывается

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def CallBack (c):    
    if c.data == "Vzal":
            bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=c.message.chat.id, message_id=c.message.message_id, reply_markup=None)
```

Как узнать, кто нажал на кнопку (нужен ID человека или его Username)?
Ведь если я использую `c.message.chat.username` - мне возращает `None`.
Или в Callback_query_handler это не возможно сделать?

Comment: Мне в `c.message.chat.username` выводит имя пользователя. Попробуйте еще `c.from_user.username`

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def CallBack (c):    
    if c.data == "Vzal":
       UM = c.from_user.username
       bot.reply_to(c.message, text = "Text" + str(UM))
       bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=c.message.chat.id, message_id=c.message.message_id, reply_markup=None)
```

Username - чтобы получить UserName пользователя
или ID - чтобы получить ID пользователя.